# Let background catch Tapped events?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp

I have a grid with a semi transparent background, and I'd like the user to be able to tap the background to close the popup.

Now I have this XAML:

```
<Grid
    Tapped="Close_Tapped">
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity=".75"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <!-- Inner border -->
    <Border
        Background="White"
        CornerRadius="5">
        <!-- Other items -->
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And the `Tapped` event should only be applied to the `Grid` background, but obviously this applies it to the entire grid.

Any ideas to have this `Tapped` event only work on the background?

Comment: In the `Close_Tapped` check if `e.OriginalSource` is a `Grid`

Comment: @dkozl Thanks! I didn't know that, please add it as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either check if `e.OriginalSource` in the `Close_Tapped` event handler is a`Grid` or add another element to the `Grid`, below other elements, which will become your background and then move `Tapped` handler there

```
<Grid>
    <Border Tapped="Close_Tapped">
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity=".75"/>
        </Border.Background>
    </Border>
    <!-- Inner border -->
    <Border
        Background="White"
        CornerRadius="5">
        <!-- Other items -->
    </Border>
</Grid>
```